# "Unfit___, but even less" or "but even more"

Tags: sentence-patterns

This sentence

> He considered himself ***unfit*** for the job, ***but even more*** for that task.

does not sound right because ***unfit*** has a negative meaning. I tried the other way:

> He considered himself ***unfit*** for the job, ***but even less*** for that task.

but this looks like a contradictory sentence.

Is there any way to put this right, without repeating "unfit"?

Comment: _So_ is badly wanting in both the sentences. I remember your having answered a question about ellipsis. That might be the case here as well. If you wish to keep out _unfit_ the second time in your sentences, you have gotta retain _so_. And _but_ and _and_ might alter the meanings distinctly.

Comment: replace more with moreso

Comment: Just in one word?

Comment: "but" is usually followed by something contradictory. You should use "and". And in the second version, you could say "and even less fit for the task".

Comment: Interesting point. thank you

Comment: I would rewrite it as , "He considered himself unfit (for the job), more so for that task."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consulting usage [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but%20even%20more%20so%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) might help bring about your agreeing with the following possibility.

- He considered himself unfit for the job, but even more so for that task.

Answer (score 0):

> More = to a greater or higher degree — often used with an adjective or adverb to form the comparative
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/more)

The important point here is the use of *degree*. It tells us that, regardless of the adjective itself, there is a scale of degree.

more unfit = unfit to a greater degree.

And the most unfit = having the greatest degree of unfitness.

From this perspective, we could even say things like “-10 is more negative than -5” and it would be clear and correct, whereas “-10 is more than -5” is clearly wrong.